# Combining / Refining two identical blocks of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two blocks of code that function exactly the same but need to fired independently in order to prevent overlap of functionality.

```js
//Block One
jQuery('.top_searchicon').on('click touchstart', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('.top_blog_search').toggleClass('active');
}));

//Block Two
jQuery('.searchicon').on('click touchstart', (function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  jQuery('.blog_search').toggleClass('active');
}));
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `jQuery('.top_searchicon, .searchicon).on...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine selectors using a comma (`,`). You can then use `is()` and a ternary to choose the relevant element to set the `active` class on. Try this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.top_searchicon, .searchicon').on('click touchstart', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $el = $(this).toggleClass('active');
        var targetClass = $el.is('.searchicon') ? '.blog_search' : '.top_blog_search';
        $(targetClass).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Note the use of the parameter in the ready handler, this enables you to still use the `$` to reference jQuery within the scope of your document.ready handler.

Comment: No problem,glad to help

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using the same event handler and checking within the event handler is to pass parameters to the event handler.

```
jQuery('.top_searchicon').on('click touchstart', function() { 
    handleClickTouchStart(".top_blog_search"); 
});
jQuery('.searchicon').on('click touchstart', function() { 
    handleClickTouchStart(".blog_search"); 
});
function handleClickTouchStart(selector)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  jQuery(selector).toggleClass('active');
}
```

This lets you add new handlers without needing to change the handler code (which would become quite messy with more than 2 options using `.is` (which is ofc fine if you only have 2, maybe 3)), eg:

```
jQuery('.another_searchicon').on('click touchstart', function() { 
    handleClickTouchStart(".another_blog_search"); 
});
```

---

The next step would be to use `-data` attributes to link the two.
This gives you the benefit of being able to add new elements without needing to change any code!

```
jQuery('.searchhandler').on('click touchstart', function() {
  e.preventDefault();
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('active');
  var other = jQuery(this).data("related");
  jQuery(other).toggleClass('active');
});
```

and change your markup to add matching -data (speculating on the markup here) :

```
<button type='button' class='searchhandler' data-related='.top_blog_search'>top search</button>
<button type='button' class='searchhandler' data-related='.blog_search'>blog search</button>

<div class='top_blog_search'></div>
...etc
```

to add another:

```
<button type='button' class='searchhandler' data-related='.another_search'>another search</button>
<div class='another_search'></div>
```